# how to add model relationship if column names are different from two tables?

Tags: php, yii

how to add relationship with these two tables if the primary key of the first table has
a different column name in the second table it is being referred to

```
e.g

Person
personid(pk),fname,lname,age

Job
jobid(pk),humanid(fk),description
```

in that example above, the humanid column's value in the job table is the the personid from the first table..
so how to create a relation ship in this two table?

I tried

```
//PERSON MODEL
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'job' => array(self::HAS_ONE,'Job','jobid')
        );
    }




//JOB MODEL
   public function relations(){
       return array(
           'person' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Person','personid')
        );
   }
```

this doesn't work...any solutions without having to rename the db columns in my database?

Comment: 'person' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Person','humanid') ?

Comment: your suggestion didn't work

Comment: 'VarName'=>array('RelationType', 'ClassName', 'ForeignKey') according to docs  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 1):

The relation in the Person model should look like this:

```
//PERSON MODEL
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'job' => array(self::HAS_ONE,'Job','humanid')
    );
}
```

Because the Job table is related to the Person table for the humanid key (personid = humanid).

If the Person and the Job tables have one-to-many relationship, you should use self::HAS_MANY instead of self::HAS_ONE ('job'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Job','humanid')).

And as яша said, the relations in the Job model should look like this:

```
//JOB MODEL
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'person' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Person','humanid')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

//JOB MODEL

```
public function relations(){
   return array(
       'person' => array(self::HAS_ONE,'Person',array('personid'=>'humanid')
    );
}
```